# Can I upload a file to server using bootstrap-fileinput? Does it support server upload like jquery multiple file uploader?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to server in C# using [bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput)

. Does it support server side data upload like [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). In jQuery File Upload you can handle file on server side using a handler. Can we do this using Bootstrap file input. I can't use multiple file uploader for some reason..Thanks in Advance

Comment: bootstrap is client side javascript and css framework, it doesnt have anything to do with serverside . for uploads you need to make sure on what platform your script is running like php, python

Comment: i am using C# as server plateform

Answer (score 2):

in HTML you will have to put it inside Form then Add a Button that fire an ajax call its the save button at the end of the form like that

```
<form id="LogoForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="upload" class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;">
                    <img"http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image")"/>
                </div>
                <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span id="btnspan" class="btn default btn-file">
                        <span id="SelectImage" class="fileinput-new">Select image </span>
                        <span id="Change" class="fileinput-exists">Change </span>
                        <input type="file" name="logoInput" id="fileup" />
                    </span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn red fileinput-exists" id="Remove" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove </a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn green" id="SaveProfilPic">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

then in JavaScript File create a normal ajax Call and pass the form as parameter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#SaveProfilPic').on('click', function () {
    var formCol = $('#LogoForm');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL of your webmethod',
        data: new FormData(formCol[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            Alert('Succsess');
        }
    });
});
```